# Archive::Zip duplicating added files - How do i update files inside a zip correctly?

Tags: perl

I have a zip file that i must update an file under a folder , the following block works "well", it add correctly the file node.ndf under the path specified.

But if i run it for the second time or more , it duplicates the file under the folder

as example:

---

first time run:

file.zip content:

manifest.v3

ns/adapt/node.ndf

---

second time run:

manifest.v3

ns/adapt/node.ndf

ns/adapt/node.ndf

---

and so on...

Here is the code im currently using:

```
$obj = Archive::Zip->new();  

$status = $obj->read($file); 

if ($status != AZ_OK) {
die('Error in file!');
    } else {
        @files = ('node.ndf');

       foreach $filea (@files) {
    $obj->addFile($filea); 
    $obj->addTreeMatching( '.', 'ns/adapt/', 'node.ndf' );
   }

   if ($obj->overwrite() != AZ_OK) {  
    print "Error in archive creation!";
    exit;

    } else {
    print "Archive created successfully!";
    }
unlink('node.ndf');
 }
```

Anyone know the correct usage of Archive::Zip in order to update a file under a folder structure at the zip file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

```
$obj->removeMember('ns/adapt/node.ndf');
$obj->addFile('node.ndf', 'ns/adapt/node.ndf');
```

or, if your `node.ndf` file has changed size or modification time, you can do both in a single step with

```
$obj->updateMember('ns/adapt/node.ndf', 'node.ndf');
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for you reply, worked as intended with:
$obj->updateMember('ns/adapt/node.ndf', 'node.ndf');